# Using break in for-await-of without ending the underlying stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, async-await, stream

In a Node.js project, I am using a `for await of` loop with a readable stream as data source, so my code conceptually looks like this:

```
for await (const item of readableStream) {
  // ...
}
```

The readable stream exists before the loop, i.e. it does not get created for the loop, but it is already there. Now the point is that I would like to be able to stop listening to this stream, i.e. I would like to `break` from the loop, but I do *not* want to close the readable stream.

If I simply do this:

```
for await (const item of readableStream) {
  if (condition) {
    break;
  }

  // ...
}
```

the loop stops as expected, but the stream gets closed. How can I achieve the same thing, *without* closing the stream?

I can't use `on('data')` directly, because the action I want to take includes running an `async` function, and hence this won't work. I know that I *could* solve this using a `Transform` or a `Writable` stream, but this seems to be some overhead I would like to avoid.

Is what I want to do possible with a `for await of` loop, and if so, how? If not, what is my best alternative?

Comment: You could possibly use something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-event on `data`. Does this result in desired behaviour?

Comment: This has worked … if you turn your comment into an answer, I will happily accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this behaviour by listening `data` event with promisified event emitter.

[`p-event`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-event) supports asynchronous iterators for this purpose:

```
const asyncIterator = pEvent.iterator(readableStream, 'data', {
  resolutionEvents: ['finish']
});

for await (const item of asyncIterator ) {
  if (condition) {
    break;
  }

  // ...
}
```